# How to view the JVM memory usage of the Play framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, performance-testing, playframework-1.x

My application is developed in Play framework 1.2.5 and it is running in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. The CPU utilization is high. So I would like to monitor the JVM of the Amazon instance. Can someone guide me on the monitoring tool for Play framework 1.2.5 application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the OS on which the JVM is running, but basically for high CPU you need to jstack to get thread dumps on the process when it is maxing the CPU and at the same time collect OS layer information on the process and it's threads.

ps -eL and jstack on linux will do the trick.

Another tip, try jconsole and jvisualvm on your JAVA_HOME/bin directories for monitoring as well.

Comment: Do you need to install jstack when using java on elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

My Play 1.x experience is a bit rusty, but we've had success with [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) to analyze a running JVM. It gives CPU and memory analytics, and lets you inspect objects while your application is running.

If you're interested in something more lightweight, and are most interested in just seeing what your application is *doing*, try running `jstack <your app's pid>`. It'll give you a thread dump, which may help you find problems.